# Possible to run eclipse kepler in dropbox?

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse, force.com-ide, setup

Newbie dev here.

I have to switch computers frequently (and not always the same computers). Instead of installing and setting up git and force.com plugin and connect to my org each time... Would it be possible to set it all up in dropbox and run eclipse kepler from dropbox?

Let me know if you've done this or think it's possible (also let me know if it's not a good idea and why.)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not advisable. Dropbox's backup algorithm is not clever enough to be solely relied on to keep your code up to date.

Just set up & use Git, it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Thanks for the input Davin... if I can add a clarification question: I was planning to set up eclipse kepler in dropbox and setup/link it to my git/salesforce accounts. Then if I have to use another computer, I can just download dropbox and have it sync. Then I don't need to redo the git/salesforce setup/linking again. So if the above works... it would be backed up on git as well ...  But that's still a bad idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could work as long as you treat Git as the master i.e. setup on the new computer using the files from Dropbox but pull from Git to get the latest code before doing any work (as we cannot trust the files stored in Dropbox). Definitely use different directories i.e. don't place your workspace folder in Dropbox, copy the files across manually.